# Upgraded Servicestack now auth always yields EmailAlreadyExists - even on logon

Tags: github, servicestack

I have upgraded to the latest ServiceStack. Now, when logging in I always get

`?f=emailAlreadyExists`

> https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md#authentication

This is not on reg, but on login?

Is this expected? If so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Enforcing [unique emails was enabled in v4.0.30](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/release-notes.md#unique-emails). It means that another OAuth account exists with your email address that's not linked to your user account, it can be disabled with:

```
AuthProvider.ValidateUniqueEmails = false;
```